# Definition of hydrodynamic force and torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, torque, flow

I am currently reading about the added mass effect. In the book I'm reading (*Added Mass of Ship Structure* by Alexandr I. Korantkin), the hydrodynamic force and torque acting on a body experiencing a non-stationary motion in an ideal infinite fluid are defined by:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\vec{R} &= -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} - \vec{\omega}\times\vec{B} \\
\vec{L} &= -\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t} -\vec{\omega}\times\vec{J} - \vec{u}_O \times \vec{B}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\vec{R}$ is the vector of force, applied to the origin of the non-stationary coordinate system attached to the body; $\vec{B}$ is the main vector of the system of momenta of pressures acting on the surface of the body; $\vec{\omega}$ is the vector of angular velocity of body rotation around the axis passing through the origin of the non-stationary coordinate system; $\vec{L}$ is the hydrodynamic torque influencing the body (computed
with respect to the origin of the non-stationary coordinate system); $\vec{J}$ is the main hydrodynamic moment influencing the surface of the body computed with respect to the origin of the non-stationary coordinate system; $\vec{u}_O$ is the vector of velocity of the origin of the non-stationary coordinate system.

The problem is that I would like to understand how this expression is derived. I've found the book the author has cited but I cannot find the derivation there. I was hoping that someone could enlighten me. More particularly I don't know what really is the main vector of the system of momenta of pressures and the main hydrodynamic moment (English is not my birth language), and I cannot find definition elsewhere.